# How do I make a table that prints the Mean and its corresponding weight of a Gaussian Mixture model?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, weights, analysis-of-means

I am successfully generating weights and means for a GMM, but I'm trying to get the results to print in a way that shows the corresponding mean for a weight.  Here's what I have now:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import pandas as pd
#bring in data here
Filename = "data name"
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=1) 
X = np.concatenate([
        rng.normal(-1, 1.5, 350), 
        rng.normal(0, 1, 500), 
        rng.normal(3, 0.5, 150)]).reshape(-1, 1) 

# Fit models with 1-10 components 
k_arr = np.arange(10) + 1 

models = [ 
        GaussianMixture(n_components=k).fit(X)
        for k in k_arr
        ]
print(models)
# Plot function 
def plot_mixture(gmm, X, show_legend=True, ax=None): 
    if ax is None: ax = plt.gca() 
    
    # Compute PDF of whole mixture 
    x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 1000) 
    logprob = gmm.score_samples(x.reshape(-1, 1)) 
    pdf = np.exp(logprob) 

# Compute PDF for each component 
    responsibilities = gmm.predict_proba(x.reshape(-1, 1)) 
    pdf_individual = responsibilities * pdf[:, np.newaxis] 
# Plot PDF of whole model 
# Plot data histogram 
    ax.hist(X, 30, density=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.4, label =Filename) 
    ax.plot(x, pdf, '-k', label='Mixture PDF') 
    
    # Plot PDF of each component 
    ax.plot(x, pdf_individual, '--', label='Component PDF') 
    ax.set_xlabel("Min") 
    ax.set_ylabel("AU") 
    if show_legend: 
        ax.legend()
# Show all models for n_components 1 to 9 
_, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=np.array([3,3])*3, dpi=100)  
for gmm, ax in zip(models, axes.ravel()): 
    plot_mixture(gmm, X, show_legend=False, ax=ax) 
    ax.set_title(f'k={gmm.n_components}') 
plt.tight_layout()
# Compute metrics to determine best hyperparameter 
AIC = [m.aic(X) for m in models] 
BIC = [m.bic(X) for m in models] 
# Plot these metrics 
plt.plot(k_arr, AIC, label='AIC') 
plt.plot(k_arr, BIC, label='BIC') 
plt.xlabel('Number of Components ($k$)') 
plt.legend()
gmm_best = models[np.argmin(AIC)] 
best_AIC = np.argmin(AIC)+1
plot_mixture(gmm_best, X)

print("Best number of components" +" "+"= "+str(best_AIC))
#here is where we build the matrix of 
Means=GaussianMixture(n_components=best_AIC).fit(X).means_
Weights= GaussianMixture(n_components=best_AIC).fit(X).weights_
Combined_means_weights = np.insert(Means, 1, Weights, axis=1)

print(Combined_means_weights) #the first number is the x-value, the second is the % of total
```

The output of the last part is:

```
Best number of components = 3
[[-1.43738314  0.57139616]
 [ 0.17327443  0.15570257]
 [ 3.01853777  0.27290127]]
```

But you can see that actually -1.437 should go with value .2729, .1732 should go with 0.57, and 3.018 should go with 0.155.

I'd ideally like to have the output be:
[[-1.43738314  0.27290127]
[0.17327443  0.57139616]
[3.01853777  0.15570257]

What the best way to do this?  Also I don't really understand the order of the output from weights_ and means_.  Why is it like that?  Thanks for the help